# setkomafont with uppercase that works robustly

Tags: fonts, koma-script, capitalization

I know that `\setkomafont` is supposed to deal with switching *fonts* but sometimes instead of switching font, I'd like to switch to uppercase. I've not found a way to do this reliably. This breaks:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\setkomafont{title}{\normalfont\uppercase}
\author{A. Author}
\title{The title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

But this works:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\uppercase}
\author{A. Author}
\title{The title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Something}
\end{document}
```

But this breaks:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\uppercase}
\author{A. Author}
\title{The title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{something}
\end{document}
```

Now, here's the one that's *really* weird:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{sen70,
  author =   {Amartya Sen},
  title =    {Collective choice and social welfare},
  publisher =    {Holden-Day},
  year =     1970}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\uppercase}
\author{A. Author}
\title{The title}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Something}
\cite{sen70}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Now, this *kind of* works in that the section heading is uppercased. But it *doesn't* work in that the "References" is set lowercase. But it is set in `normalfont`...

I know that `\uppercase` doesn't behave like a font switching command, but is there a robust way to do what I want?

I guess I could create a virtual font with the capitals in place of the lc letters, but there *must* be a better way...

Comment: Just in case you're using LuaTeX: you could try the approach I've written in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109476/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Imho there is no better way. A font is the best solution. Some of the problems with `\uppercase` & friends are described in the FAQ: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-casechange. In your example there are the additional problems that you don't know where in the code the upper case command is executed and you can have various arguments.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a layer over `\section` and redefine `\author`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\author#1{\gdef\@author{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\let\scr@section\section
\def\section{\@ifstar\seamus@sections\seamus@section}
\def\seamus@sections#1{\scr@section*{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\def\seamus@section{\@dblarg{\seamus@section@}}
\def\seamus@section@[#1]#2{%
  \scr@section[\MakeUppercase{#1}]{\MakeUppercase{#2}}}
\makeatother
```

The method advertised by `source2e.pdf` of terminating the sixth parameter passed to `\@startsection` with `\MakeUppercase` doesn't work with **scrartcl**.

Comment: When using this solution in conjunction with hyperref, change the `\MakeUppercase` command with `\solelyuppercase` provided by the package [stringstrings](https://ctan.org/pkg/stringstrings?lang=en)