# Applying an operation only to capitals

Tags: conditionals, capitalization, parsing

I'd like to apply a function to capitals only so that:

```
\emphcaps{YaWeH}
```

Outputs like:

```
\emph{Y}a\emph{W}e\emph{H}
```

Preferably without using too many packages (I already use `memoir`).

NOTES: I use XeLaTeX (as it's bidi support seems best).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got this answer from `dl903` on `irc://irc.freenode.net/#latex`

```
\def\capOnlyEmph#1{\mycaps#1\relax.}\def\mycaps#1#2.{\ifnum`#1<97\emph{#1}\else#1\fi\ifx#2\relax\else\mycaps#2.\fi}

\capOnlyEmph{ALLaH, YaWeH}
```

I use it in my document to format transliterations from semitic/arab languages. (instead of the `\emph` command i use the `relsize` package to make the capitals 15% smaller, and i format the whole thing with a different font)

Comment: Of course you'll have noticed that only the first letter is italicized, provided it's uppercase. This code is wrong, because it only examines the *first* letter. The cause, of course, is the double L.

Comment: Swapping `#2` and `\relax` would help a bit.

Answer (score 16):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\emphcap}[1]{\begingroup\emph@cap#1\@nil\endgroup}
\def\emph@cap#1{%
  \ifx#1\@nil
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \emph@@cap{#1}%
  \fi
  \emph@cap}
\def\emph@@cap#1{%
  \ifnum\uccode`#1=`#1\relax
    \itshape#1\emph@captrue
  \else
    \ifemph@cap\/\else\fi\upshape#1\emph@capfalse
  \fi}
\newif\ifemph@cap
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\emphcap{THiSiSWHaTIWaNT}
\end{document}
```

This assumes that your input contains only normal letters (no accents). The result is really ugly.

[image]

Comment: My eyes! They bleed!

Comment: I cannot understand this code, but given what the question asks, could this be adapted to a robust answer to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33148/setkomafont-with-uppercase-that-works-robustly

Comment: @Seamus No, it won't be robust.

Comment: @egreg You mean it's been uniquely designed for only this question. That is short of a miracle:)

Comment: Nice answer! I'd have picked it is it weren't for a shorter one i got in irc.

Answer (score 15):

An approach using LaTeX3: the important command is `\regex_replace_all:nnN`. Its first argument is a regular expression (here, `[A-Z]` matches any uppercase letter); its second argument the replacement, here `\textit` followed by `\0` (what the regular expression matched); and the third is a *token list variable* on which we want to do the replacement.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \emphcap #1
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { [A-Z] } { \c{textit} \0 } \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\emphcap{THiS iS \texttt{WHaT} I WaNT}
\end{document}
```

Of course, spaces are preserved, as are any formatting commands within the argument (here I put `\texttt` for the demo). This should work with any recent enough version of the `l3kernel` and `l3experimental` bundles (February 2012, say).

Alternatively, you could use the replacement

```
\regex_replace_all:nnN { [A-Z]+ } { \c{textit} \cB\{ \0 \cE\} } \l_tmpa_tl
```

I changed the regex to match any number of consecutive uppercase letters, and I changed the replacement text to add braces around the argument to `\textit`. This avoids the extra space inserted in `\textit{N}\textit{T}`. The output:

[image: Output of the code choosing the second replacement]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your LaTeX3 code. I like to see how a problem can be solved with different kinds of LaTeX. Maybe in near future it should be good practice to show how one can solve a problem with different kinds of LaTeX like it is shown on this question.

Comment: Awesome code, Bruno! `:)`

Comment: Beautiful code Bruno.

Comment: Very nice and concise answer!  I've been searching the regex route myself, but failed.

Answer (score 14):

Ok, here is an other approach dedicated to LuaLaTeX fans (and future fans of LuaLaTeX). I think it is a good example to show how easy it is to write a few (easy to understand) lines of Lua code. In the provided Lua code one can check the input string for every char and format any LaTeX string you need without cryptic TeX commands.

It is good practice to write the lua functions in a separate file with the extension .lua. For this MWE I use the `filecontents` environment instead to provide an extra file for the lua script.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{luaFunctions.lua}
function emphcaps(input) 
    outputString = ""
    len = string.len(input)

    for i = 1, len, 1 do --for each char in string
      ascii =  string.byte(input, i) -- convert the char in a decimal 

      if(ascii >= 65 and ascii <= 90) then -- upper case (look to the ASCII table)
        outputString = outputString.."\\emph{"..string.char(ascii).."}"
      else
        outputString = outputString..string.char(ascii)
      end

    end

    tex.print(outputString)
end
\end{filecontents*}

% read the external lua file to declare the defined function,
% but without execute the Lua function
\directlua{dofile("luaFunctions.lua")}

% latex command to execute the lua function
\def\emphcaps#1{\directlua{emphcaps("#1")}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\emphcaps{YaWeH}\\
\emphcaps{LuaLaTeX}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** After the great comment from Khaled Hosny I want to provide a very straight solution. It shows again the power of Lua ;-). The new function replaces all (thats what the `+` after `%u` stands for) upper chars (thats what the `%u` stands for) with `\emph{}`. The `%1` holds the value which is surrounded by the `( )` in the search pattern.

```lua
function emphcaps(input)
    output, count = string.gsub(input, '(%u+)', '\\emph{%1}')
    tex.print(output)
end
```

Comment: Good example. In true TeX spirit there is no true way:) Keep these Lua answers coming.

Comment: This can be much simplified by using `string.gsub()` e.g. `string.gsub(input, '(%u+)', '\\emph{%1}')` (or `unicode.utf8.gsub` to handle Unicode strings)

Comment: @Khaled Hosny: Great comment! Thanks a lot! Thats the spirit of Lua, how I like it.

Comment: I use XeTeX, which I believe is different from LuaTex -- I'd love to use Lua over TeX-programming though.

Answer (score 12):

Consider rather writing a macro for this type of issue. For example you can create a command for your example as follows:

```
\newcommand{\yaweh}{%
  \emph{Y}a\emph{W}e\emph{H}
}
```

The advantage of this, is that also your mark-up can be more meaningful.

As per request and a bit of a different approach to egreg's solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\uP#1{%
\@tfor\next:=#1\do{%
 \ifnum \expandafter
    \the\expandafter\lccode
      \expandafter`\next=\expandafter
       \number\expandafter`\next
       \next
 \else 
     \textit{\next}%
\fi}%
}
\begin{document}
\uP{aLLah}
\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry if it was not clear from my question but i want it to be dynamic. i.e. next thing i want to use it for `ALLaH` and many other words.

Comment: @user62152 Please see amended post.

Comment: @user62152 Couldn't you set it up one for each deity? I mean, as long as you avoid the Hindu pantheon it shouldn't take you that long.

Comment: Sorry, but in the post i say already that i'd like to "apply a function to each capital". That function will be something different then `\emph` eventually.