# Towards a \ucshape and \textuc command for uppercase text (XeTeX, LuaTeX)

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, capitalization, opentype

While we have `\textit` and `\textsc`, `\itshape` and `\scshape` etc., there's no `\textuc` and `\ucshape` to typeset its argument in uppercase. There is `\MakeUppercase`, but -- as uppercase is not a font style -- it's not a font selection command and cannot be used like one. That's why it's of no use in, e.g., formatting headings. There's the [seamus-](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/215/seamus)[egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) [workaround,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33148/setkomafont-with-uppercase-that-works-robustly) but that has its limitations, for example when exotic languages are used: `\section{daß}` produces »DAß« rather than »DASS«, etc.

Traditionally, the only way towards a proper `\textuc`/`\ucshape` seemed to be via creating a virtual font in which all lowercase letters are replaced by uppercase ones. While I've seen a couple of people suggesting that approach, I don't think anyone has ever done it, probably because it's tedious and inflexible, as it's always tied to one specific font.

My question is if it might be a good idea to rethink that issue now that we have Xe and Lua, where we can use OpenType Fonts and, via fontspec, OpenType feature files. In those feature files, we can define substitution rules that can be switched on and off. In OpenType, an f_i ligature, for example, is produced via such a substitution rule, saying »whenever in the code you come across an `f` followed by an `i`, replace the two by the glyph `f_i` in the output«. To tentatively answer my own question: yes, it might be. Consider the following example. [edit: now including a comparison with the `\MakeTextUppercase` command from the `textcase` package barbara [mentioned.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100336/towards-a-textuc-command-for-uppercase-text-xe-lua#comment217223_100336)]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec,blindtext,microtype,filecontents,textcase}

\begin{filecontents*}{universalcaps.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;

feature caps {

lookup ligatures {
  sub f_i by F I;
  sub f_l by F L;
  sub f_f_l by F F L;
  sub f_f_i by F F I;
  sub f_f by F F;
  sub f_j by F J;
  sub f_f_j by F F J;
  sub f_t by F T;
  sub f_f_t by F F T;
} ligatures;

lookup eszett {
  sub germandbls by S S;
} eszett;

lookup single {
  sub [a-z] by [A-Z];
  sub agrave by Agrave;
  sub aacute by Aacute;
  sub acircumflex by Acircumflex;
  sub atilde by Atilde;
  sub adieresis by Adieresis;
  sub aring by Aring;
  sub ccedilla by Ccedilla;
  sub egrave by Egrave;
  sub eacute by Eacute;
  sub ecircumflex by Ecircumflex;
  sub edieresis by Edieresis;
  sub igrave by Igrave;
  sub iacute by Iacute;
  sub icircumflex by Icircumflex;
  sub idieresis by Idieresis;
  sub eth by Eth;
  sub ntilde by Ntilde;
  sub ograve by Ograve;
  sub oacute by Oacute;
  sub ocircumflex by Ocircumflex;
  sub otilde by Otilde;
  sub odieresis by Odieresis;
  sub ugrave by Ugrave;
  sub uacute by Uacute;
  sub ucircumflex by Ucircumflex;
  sub udieresis by Udieresis;
  sub yacute by Yacute;
  sub thorn by Thorn;
  sub ydieresis by Ydieresis;
  sub oe by OE;
  sub ae by AE;
  sub scaron by Scaron;
  sub zcaron by Zcaron;
} single;

} caps;
\end{filecontents*}

\setmainfont[FeatureFile=universalcaps.fea]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont[FeatureFile=universalcaps.fea]{TeX Gyre Heros}

\newcommand*{\ucshape}{\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+caps}}
\newcommand{\textuc}[1]{{\ucshape #1}}

\setkomafont{section}{\ucshape}

\begin{document}
\section{Lorem Ipsum}

\textuc{\blindtext
àéîàáâãäåæ çèéêëìíîï ðñòóôõö ùúûüýþÿœš
fi ff fl ffi ffl fj ffj}

\MakeTextUppercase{daß}
\textuc{daß}

\begin{titlepage}
\ucshape
\begin{center}
John Doe\par
{\huge Title}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

This will create a feature file, adding to whatever font is loaded a new feature called `caps` that can be turned on and off like any other. Note that this will work with TrueType fonts as well, `{Georgia}` etc; `fontspec` seems to transfer what's in the .fea file to even non-OpenType fonts.

- Are there any potential drawbacks that I may not have had in mind? I'm still thinking it seems too simple to be true. (While it may be simple, it may of course still be a lot of work to take are of all lowercase glyphs in advanced multi-language fonts).
- Has anyone else ever done or seen something like that? I find it hard to believe I should be the first to come up with that idea...
- If noone has done it so far, would it be a good idea to turn it into a little package?

Comment: I don't know why it isn't a standard feature for OT fonts.

Comment: indeed it would be a piece of cake for a font designer to add it to the font they're designing. I've never seen it though, and I've looked at lots of OT fonts over the past years, even ones that are far beyond my budget. I guess one of the reasons it's not implemented is that any DTP software or word processor is able to turn text into uppercase with just one click. So for a font designer there's simply no need to implement that as a font feature, unless they're thinking of people like us.

Comment: maybe i'm confused, or too provincial, but isn't this essentially what the ams document classes provide with their `\MakeTextUppercase`?  (although i haven't explored whether it works with non-cm/lm fonts, and clearly, something special needs to be done for turkish dotted vs. undotted "i"s.)

Comment: the way I see it, `\MakeTextUppercase`, which I'm well aware of, is fundamentally different from what I'm looking for. The former changes (the case of) its argument, while the latter is supposed to work like a font selection command. You're right though, I should add that of course we also need a `\ucshape` command. And that's where the difference becomes even clearer: we simply cannot use `\MakeTextUppercase` the same way we can use `\ucshape`, `\itshape` etc. Plus there's the language problems you mention: `\MakeTextUppercase{daß},` but `\textuc{daß}.`

Comment: @NilsL Maybe you could detail a bit further in what sense it exactly should work like a font selection command? Should it just be in effect until the end of the current group? Does it need to work across line/paragraph/page boundaries?

Comment: @Daniel yes, it needs to work across line/paragraph/page/group boundaries, as the aim is to have `\ucshape` be perfectly interchangeable with `\itshape` and the like. Whereever I can use `\itshape,` I want to be able to use `\ucshape` in the exact same way.

Comment: The Libertine font offers the feature `ss03` that (at least) turns every `ß` into `ss` (but as one glyph).

Comment: This seems a very nice idea.  One application that comes to mind is uppercasing texts containing mathematical formulae - the symbols in them are (at least in traditional TeX, I don't know too much about Lua/XeTeX) rendered in *another* font, so your *f*'s and *x*'s wouldn't get capitalized.  (AFAIR, AMSLaTeX's `\MakeTextUppercase` supports this too, but maybe it is just needlessly complicated now that we have OT fonts?)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel -- interesting! Looks like Libertine is one of the few fonts designed with the limitations of *TeX in mind.

Comment: Feature files are font specific (they depend on the actual glyph names in the font which may vary from font to another), and does not work with XeTeX of course. Since you are using a LuaTeX-only solution, you are better writing lua code to process node lists and work on actual Unicode values and add all the intelligence you want (upper-casing can be complex and is language sensitive).

Comment: @KhaledHosny -- thanks for clarifying. I wasn't aware that feature files, as of yet, are Lua only (I do see it now in the documentation). As for the glyph names: yes, font designers are free to name glyphs anyway they like. There seems to be some consensus though, as I haven't had any trouble with the glyphs in my example. I've tested it with quite a few fonts from various producers (major commercial foundries, small independent ones, the »community«, etc.). You're right though, there might be an even smarter means for that purpose, particularly when a lot of languages are to be taken care of.

Comment: PS: what would be the authorities I should consult if I wanted to take the road you're suggesting (processing node lists)? I'm not familiar yet with what exactly nodes (in the Lua sense) are and how they work. The LuaTeX Reference Manual, for example, seems to be addressed at people who already know these things.

Comment: [LuaTeX wiki](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Main_Page) has some good examples.

Comment: I don't think, that `\ucshape` and `\itshape`, `\scshape`,… should be completely interchangeable. They work on different levels: `\ucshape` would change unicode codepoints; `\itshape`, `\scshape` only change the glyphs representing the same unicode codepoint. An all uppercase text has less information than a mixed case text, in contrast to a `\itshape` text compared to an `\upshape` text. This might be not important in English, but in German it is, as nouns always start with uppercase letters.

Comment: As for drawbacks, replacing `ß` by `SS` via a feature file wouldn't adapt to changes in hyphenation.  Consider, _e.g._, bei-ßen _vs._ BEIS-SEN in German reformed orthography.

Comment: As for other's work, there's a somewhat related thread focusing on _ß_ in `Newsgroups: de.comp.text.tex Subject: ngerman Bug? Silbentrennung bei Doppel-S Date: Thu, 27 Sep 2007 15:38:40 +0200 Message-ID: <5m1q31FbdfbqU1@mid.dfncis.de>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A full implementation in LuaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{luatexbase}
\usepackage{luatexbase-attr}

\newluatexattribute\uppercaseattr


\begin{luacode*}
  local ucattr = luatexbase.attributes.uppercaseattr
  local GLYPH = node.id("glyph")
  local function makeuppercase(head)
      local orighead = head
      local string = unicode.utf8
      while head do
          if head.id == GLYPH then
              local att = node.has_attribute(head,ucattr)
              if att then
                  if head.char == 223 then -- ß
                      -- insert two 'S' glyphs
                      head.char = 83
                      orighead = node.insert_before(orighead,head,node.copy(head))
                  elseif head.char == 64258 then -- fl
                      head.char = 70 -- F
                      orighead = node.insert_before(orighead,head,node.copy(head))
                      head.char = 76 -- L
                  elseif head.char == 64256 then -- ff
                      head.char = 70 -- F
                      orighead = node.insert_before(orighead,head,node.copy(head))
                      head.char = 70 -- F
                  elseif head.char == 64257 then -- fi
                      head.char = 70 -- F
                      orighead = node.insert_before(orighead,head,node.copy(head))
                      head.char = 73 -- I
                  elseif head.char == 64259 then -- ffi
                      head.char = 70 -- F
                      orighead = node.insert_before(orighead,head,node.copy(head))
                      head.char = 70 -- F
                      orighead = node.insert_before(orighead,head,node.copy(head))
                      head.char = 73 -- I
                  elseif head.char == 64260 then -- ffl
                      head.char = 70 -- F
                      orighead = node.insert_before(orighead,head,node.copy(head))
                      head.char = 70 -- F
                      orighead = node.insert_before(orighead,head,node.copy(head))
                      head.char = 76 -- L
                  else
                      head.char = string.byte(string.upper(string.char(head.char)))
                  end
              end
          end
          head = head.next
      end
      return orighead
  end

  function makeuppercase_hbox(head,groupcode)
      local orighead = head
      if groupcode == "adjusted_hbox" or groupcode == "hbox" then
           makeuppercase(head)
      end
      return orighead
  end

  luatexbase.add_to_callback("hpack_filter",makeuppercase_hbox,"makeuppercasehbox")
  luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter",makeuppercase,"makeuppercase")
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand*\ucshape{\uppercaseattr=1}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textuc}{\ucshape}

\begin{document}
\hsize 7.2cm
\newcommand\sample{Draußen \i \ij\ ffl fluffiest fish \textit{König} \textcolor{blue}{àéîàáâãäåæ} çèéêëìíîï  ff \hbox{ðñòóôõö} ùúûüýþÿœš}


Lowercase {\ucshape \sample} Lowercase

Lowercase \textuc{\sample} Lowercase

% textcolor doesn't work in LaTeX's \MakeUppercase
% Lowercase \MakeUppercase{\sample} Lowercase


\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

The program above just manipulates the nodelist iff the given attribute is set (to any value). Attributes are grouped, just like any TeX assignment.

It's a bit more complicated than I thought because we need to treat `\hbox{}`es separately.

Comment: I'm impressed! I doesn't yet seem to treat `\textuc{ffi or ß}` correctly (they're not turned into *FFI* and *SS*), but I'm assuming this would be possible with some additions (?).

Comment: @NilsL I've updated the proof of concept to a full implementation.

Comment: ß has an uppercase variant, which is mandatory in certain situations. So there need to be at least some way to specify, whether SS or uppercase ß should be used.

Comment: @Toscho Somebody else has to do that :) I will never ever create code that produces an so called upper case 'ß'...

Comment: @Toscho for technocrats, for people lacking any typographic sensitivity, or for anyone who can't deal with the fact that the upper- and lower-case Roman alphabets are two different things in their own rights and with their own logics -- it might be good to include that as an option. However, into *my* texts,  that blown-up version of a lower-case ligature will find its way only over my dead body. `//:-=(`

Comment: @NilsL: Nowadays, no regular reader thinks of ß as a ligature. It has become a regular if special letter instead. Some time ago, the ligature ß was the exception to the usual ss/sz writing. Nowadays, all uppercase SS and ss for hyphenation seem the exception to the usual ß.

Comment: This does not work any more with a new version of LuaTeX (2019).

Comment: @user125730 Fixed. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: No problem. What was the reason?

Comment: @user125730 The node ids are not fixed. The glyph node used to be #37, I don't know what it is now. To get around the code numbers, I can ask with `node.id("glyph")` for the number. I iterate through all the nodes ("things") in the paragraphs and look at the glyphs only. This is what `if head.id == GLYPH then...` does. But it GLPHY has the wrong value, nothing happens (in the best case). So instead of hard coding the id there, I ask for the current value of it.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I can't offer a macro-based `\ucshape`, I can point to an implementation for `\textuc` which can cope with accents in a flexible way.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Allow for likely changes to expl3
\cs_if_exist:NTF \text_uppercase:n
  { \tl_put_right:Nn \l_text_exclude_arg_tl { \textcolor } }
  {
    \cs_new_eq:NN \text_uppercase:n \tl_upper_case:n
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tl_change_case_exclude_tl { \textcolor } 
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \textuc { +m } { \text_uppercase:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{Lorem Ipsum}

\textuc{Draußen \i \ij\ ffl fluffiest fish
  \textit{König} \textcolor{blue}{àéîàáâãäåæ} çèéêëìíîï  ff \hbox{ðñòóôõö} ùúûüýþÿœš}

\MakeTextUppercase{daß}
\textuc{daß}

\end{document}
```

This is expandable and will copy with a range of LaTeX input, though at present there are edge cases: you need something that produces 'pure text'. As it happens at the macro layer, it will work with XeTeX as well as LuaTeX. A version which recognises language-specific changes (Turkic i/dotless-i, Greek accent remove, Lithuanian accent 'fun', Dutch IJ ligature) is also available.

At present, the implementation in `expl3` is called `\tl_upper_case:n`, though this is likely to be renamed to `\text_uppercase:n` (with improved features) in the near future: my answer reflects that.