# Alternative (lowercase) list-of headings for small caps in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, small-caps

Suppose we were using small caps (rather than, e.g., bold face) to format a sectioning level in our TOC, say, `section`.

Consequently, we would use the appropriate alternative spelling of the section titles, to make sure the TOC entries will appear in small-caps only (rather mixed with upper-case letters, which looks clumsy) -- as, so far, there's no such thing as an [upper- or lower-case command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100336/towards-a-ucshape-and-textuc-command-for-uppercase-text-xetex-luatex) that can be used functionally identically to (and in combination with) the text style commands we already have (there's no `\lcshape\scshape`).

```
\section[lorem ipsum]{Lorem Ipsum}
```

But how to proceed with things like the names of `\listoffigures` and the likes? What would be the most elegant way to patch them before they get written to the TOC file?

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tocstyle,blindtext}

\settocfeature[toc][1]{entryhook}{\normalfont\scshape}

\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\itshape}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section[lorem ipsum]{Lorem Ipsum}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}
  \dots
  \caption{\dots}\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `\MakeLowercase` you could automatically make your sections titles for the toc lowercase without manually specifying a short title.

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tocstyle,blindtext}

\settocfeature[toc][1]{entryhook}{\normalsize\scshape\MakeLowercase}

\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\large\itshape}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Lorem Ipsum}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}
  \dots
  \caption{\dots}\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to  @DavidCarlisle for pointing out the advantages of `\MakeLowercase` compared to `\lowercase`!

Comment: that's indeed the result I'm looking for. I can't believe I wasn't aware of `\lowercase`, or rather of the fact that it can be used that conveniently in this specific situation. Will run a real-world test to see how robust it is. I expect problems with certain characters (ligatures, German "ß" et al.), but in my current situation, that will certainly suffice.

Comment: @NilsL \MakeLowercase is the latex command wrapping \lowercase and will do the right thing (more often) with accented characters etc

Comment: yes, I'm aware of `\MakeLowercase` and how it works, but I guess implementing it for the purpose at hand will be a bit more tricky.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you want to post a `\MakeLowercase` answer? I'll happily delete my answer.

Comment: @samcarter no, but you could edit yours:-)

Comment: @NilsL why tricky? You can just replace `\lowercase` by `\MakeLowercase` in the above answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Edited - Thanks for your comments!

Comment: +1 for the excellent suggestion to use `\MakeLowercase` :-)

Comment: the `\MakeLowercase` solution [breaks](https://pastebin.com/fJYwcEWF) as soon as `hyperref` comes into play. But `\lowercase` seems to work well even in a fairly complex project I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I wrote a little package for this use case: `lccaps`. It basically does what samcarter's answer does. (One minor difference is that it uses `\MakeTextLowercase`, thus being a little more robust, one could say.) The solution then looks a little more compact any case:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrartcl}
  \setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\itshape}
\usepackage{lccaps}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
  \settocfeature[toc][1]{entryhook}{\textlcc}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section*{Lorem Ipsum}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Lorem Ipsum}
\blindtext    
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

[image: output]