# All capitals for Latex headings

Tags: pandoc

I want the titles of some of the headers in my Latex document (specifically part and chapter) to be uppercase like they are in [classicthesis](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/).
I also want to avoid changes to the Table of Contents.
I am generating my document using Pandoc so I want to avoid having to manually add code to the document other than the style file I am inserting at the beginning.
I am using KOMA Script `scrbook` and LuaLatex.

This is what I have tried so far:

1. `titlesec` package does not work with KOMA script so I am using the `\setkomafont` commands.
2. `\setkomafont` do not work with `\MakeUppercase` or `\uppercase` because those commands take arguments.
3. It is [recommended](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33148/setkomafont-with-uppercase-that-works-robustly) to use a font to make the text uppercase, however setting `Letters=Uppercase` in `\newfontfamily` using `fontspec` for EB Garamond does not work.
4. Using `\renewcommand` for `\part` and `\chapter` works for parts but not for chapters and it also changes the table of contents.
5. Using smallcaps at a larger font size like [this thesis](https://github.com/Ritterbecks/Hausarbeit) gives the wrong optical sizing.
6. My last option is to use [this LuaTex script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100336/towards-a-ucshape-and-textuc-command-for-uppercase-text-xetex-luatex/) but it is missing some ligatures like `tt` which I will now have to manually add to the script.

Am I missing something? There must be a simpler way to get upper case text?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a pandoc Lua filter to do this:

```lua
-- file: uppercase-headings.lua
local text = require 'text'
function Header (h)
  return pandoc.walk_block(h,
    {Str = function (s) return pandoc.Str(text.upper(s.text)) end}
  )
end
```

Use by passing it to pandoc via the `--lua-filter` option.